# Bootstrap `input-group-addon` is far from input when `width: auto` is set

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script type="application/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form id="form1" class="well form-horizontal" action="/base_url/update" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input1">Field 1</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10 input-group">
    <input style="width:auto" id="input1" min="0" name="input1" class="form-control" maxlength="20" value="0" type="number">
    <span class="input-group-addon">sm<sup>3</sup></span>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

How to make the input-group-addon to appear near the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because Bootstrap is expecting the input to fill up the "remaining space". If you want adjust the width of the textfield, you should change the width of `.input-group` instead of the input.

As an example:

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="application/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" class="well form-horizontal" action="/base_url/update" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group" style="width: 200px">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input1">Field 1</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10 input-group">
      <input id="input1" min="0" name="input1" class="form-control" maxlength="20" value="0" type="number">
      <span class="input-group-addon">sm<sup>3</sup></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `style="width:auto"` from the element

```
<input id="input1" min="0" name="input1" class="form-control" maxlength="20" value="0" type="number">
```

Bootstrap handles that for you anyway, so there's no reason to put it inline. :)